# T- invariant subspace and continuous functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C(\mathbb R)$ be the vector space of all continuous functions over $\mathbb R$. For $f,g \in C(\mathbb R)$, define the linear map $T_f: C(\mathbb R) \rightarrow C(\mathbb R)$ by $T_f(g)=g \circ f$.

Then, $(T_f(g))(x)=g(f(x))$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. For every such $f$, find a nontrivial $T_f$-invariant subspace.

I know that a subspace $W$ of $V$ is $T$-invariant if $T(W) \subseteq W$, and nontrivial just means it's not the zero subspace or the entire space.

So would I just let $W$ be a subspace of $C(\mathbb R)$ and use the linear transformation properties to prove that $T(W) \subseteq W$?

Comment: Yes, guess a subspace and then prove it $T$-invariant.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang How would I show it's nontrivial though? Or is it based on my initial assumption?

Comment: Your guess should be something like $W=\{f(x)\mid f(x)$shares xxx properties$\}$. Promise that $W\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint: constant functions are quite continuous.

Comment: So I should let the set of all constant functions be my subspace?

Comment: it's worth a try!

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a bit confused though, isn't zero a constant function? How can I make sure my subspace isn't just the zero subspace?

Comment: any subspace contains $0$. The real question should be whether it contains a function which is not $0$. If it does, then it is not the zero subspace.

Comment: So would it be sufficient to just define my subspace as the set of all constant functions? Are there any other nontrivial, T-invariant subspaces in $C(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: I am not sure why this question is confusing me, maybe it's because I'm not fully sure what it's asking.

Comment: The question is asking you to find a non-trivial $T_f$-invariant subspace $W$. This means that your job is: 1) Find a candidate set $W$ (for example, constant functions). 2) Show that $W$ is a subspace which is the non-zero subspace. 3)  Show that $W$ is $T_f$ invariant: $T_f(W) \subseteq W$.